# What's the difference between fontsize and scale?

Tags: fontsize, scale

In the `\newwatermark` two options fontsize=15pt and scale=10,What's the difference between them?

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[printwatermark]{xwatermark}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}
    \chapter{title}
    
    \newwatermark[pagex={1,2,5,7},fontfamily=put,color=gray!25,angle=45,fontsize=15pt,scale=10,
xpos=0,ypos=0]{draft}

\blinddocument
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The default value of `fontsize` is 1cm (although the documentation maintains it's 5cm), the default of `scale` is 1.

The keys are independent of each other, so you get the same result with just `fontsize=10cm` as with just `scale=10`.

You also get the same with `fontsize=15pt,scale=10` as with just `fontsize=150pt`.

However, note that `xwatermark` uses `catoptions` that's not compatible with the most recent LaTeX kernel. You can “fix” the issue by adding

```
\RequirePackage[2020-02-02]{latexrelease}
```

as the very first line in your document, but be aware that this throws away several features of the newer kernel.

Comment: Is there another package better than xwatermark and updated ?

Comment: @user97 There's `draftwatermark`

Comment: If the font has hints the proportion of characters in the font will depend on the font size while scale literally just scales up the size of a given font size; the characters will actually look different. AFAIK the type 1 fonts used in modern TeX have hints.